# Package name showing up on battery stats instead of app's friendly name

Tags: android

My app's friendly name is not being listed on my phone's battery statistics. It shows instead the package name like "com.example.main" and a generic icon next to it.

My manifest file has `android:label` correctly placed under `application` and the app's friendly name does appear elsewhere (e.g., list of running apps).

Any ideas?

Edit: 
My `<manifest>` header:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.main"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

My `<application>` tag declared in the manifest:

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.main.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: share some code of manifest..?

Comment: Anything specific? My `<application>` tag is fairly standard.

Comment: share the complete manifest.

Comment: The complete manifest is big. Anything specific I should look for?

Answer (score 0):

I think android 1st consider name if it exist it uses that else it uses label for name. I have created a simple android app and tested it.  here i found that it is only having label (not name).

Comment: Where is it taking the name from?

Comment: for name - u specified in label . just remove name from ur manifest and try again.

Comment: Yes but my label is specified in the manifest. And the name there does appear in other parts of the system (e.g., running apps, installed apps, security options, etc.). Only in the battery stats it does not show up.

Comment: I am saying not to specify name for application node can solve your problem.

Comment: To know about what u saying, i think we must see device manufacturer source code of device OS. It might be result of device specific or that screen takes App name only.